# How to incorporate styling into Messaging.sendEmail()

Tags: apex, send-email

Is it possible to include a `style` tag, either within the `head` tag or onto the `style` attribute of the `body` tag, send it with `Messaging.sendEmail()`, and have it actually send it with that styling?

I've tried both of the options I mentioned and it seems like `Messaging.sendEmail()` sanitizes the `htmlBody` value and removes *certain* style tags it does not like such as margin-block.

For example, I've sent the following `Messaging.SingleEmailMessage` object:

```
String html = '<html>';
html += '<body style="margin-block:0px !important;display:block;">';
html += '<p>test</p><p>tester</p><p>testing</p>';
html += '</body></html>';

Messaging.SingleEmailMessage message = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
message.settoAddresses(new String[] { /*your email*/ });
message.setsubject('Test');
message.setHtmlBody(html);
Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] messages =   new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> {message};
Messaging.SendEmailResult[] results = Messaging.sendEmail(messages);
```

Upon checking the html of the email, I see the following:

```
<body style="display: block;font-family: Verdana;font-size: 12.0px;">
   <p>test</p>
   <p>tester</p>
   <p>testing</p>
</body>
```

It kept `display: block` but removed the others. Why?

Comment: Are you sure it's Salesforce, and not your email client?

Comment: No I'm not, it could be my email clients. I've tried with multiple but the behaviors indicate it could be from the email client. Then how are we supposed to send styled emails through Apex?

Answer (score 3):

It's definitely your mail client(s). I tested your code in my org, and then used Gmail's "view original" feature to take a look at the raw message, and I got this:

```
------=_Part_56794_1475222677.1625151156936
Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary="----=_Part_56793_897998198.1625151156936"

------=_Part_56793_897998198.1625151156936
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

testtestertesting

Brian Fear

_____________________________________________________________________
Powered by Salesforce
http://www.salesforce.com/

<font color="red">Brian Fear</font>

_____________________________________________________________________
Powered by Salesforce
http://www.salesforce.com/

------=_Part_56793_897998198.1625151156936
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

<html><body style="margin-block:0px !important;display:block;"><p>test</p><p>tester</p><p>testing</p><br><br><font color="red">Brian Fear</font>
<br>
<br>_____________________________________________________________________
<br>Powered by Salesforce
<br>http://www.salesforce.com/<br><img src="https://redacted.my.salesforce.com/servlet/servlet.ImageServer?oid=abc&esid=xyz&from=ext"></body></html>
------=_Part_56793_897998198.1625151156936--
```

*(Note: reacted my image URL, but everything else is exactly as I received it.)*

Curiously, in Gmail, the style isn't rendered, as you've observed:

```
<div style="display:block"><p>test</p><p>tester</p><p>testing</p><br><br><font color="red">Brian Fear</font>
```

---

I can only surmise that, for whatever reason, I don't see a font attribute here, nor the margin-block CSS; this clearly demonstrates that clients are going to what clients are going to do. Also, MDN suggests that not even all browsers support this particular style, so you might just be out of luck on that specific style. Other styles may or may not work, it's just going to be up to you to test clients or do some research on the Internet to figure out what will be supported by your potential clients.